# Can you reference other queries in Elasticsearch percolator?

Tags: elasticsearch

can percolator queries reference other stored query docs in a percolator index? For example, given I have the following Boolean query, with `_id=1`, already indexed in the percolator:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "tag": "wow" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Could I have another query, with `_id=2`, indexed (note that I'm making up the `_percolator_ref_id` terms query key):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "term": { "tag": "elasticsearch" } },
        { "terms" : { "_percolator_ref_id": [1] } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I percolated the following document:

```
{ "tag": "wow" }
```

I would expect both `_id=1` and `_id=2` queries to match. Does some functionality like `_percolator_ref_id` exist?

Thanks!

**Edit:** To clarify, I do not know beforehand how many query references appear in a given query (e.g., the `_id=2` query could reference 10 other queries potentially).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below

2 queries are registered in below index

```
PUT myindex
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "query1": {
                "type": "percolator"    
            },
            "query": {
                "type": "percolator"
            },
            "field": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use bool and must/should to combine different queries

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "percolate": {
            "field": "query",
            "document": {
              "field": "fox jumps over the lazy dog"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "percolate": {
            "field": "query1",
            "document": {
              "field": "fox jumps over the lazy dog"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I had not considered storing multiple percolator fields in the same document. What if, however, I do not know beforehand how many _other_ queries will be referenced in a query (e.g., `_id=2` in my example above could potentially need to reference 10 other queries)? Does this solution accommodate that? I will edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: There is no option to link percolator by Ids. What do can do is create percolators with different names ex you can add two percolators named query and query1 in mappings. If a new percolator doc is added you can add it to either of group. While applying percolator to a document you can only specify field like query/query1 you cannot use id for it

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation! Accepting this answer as it's probably closest to the functionality I am seeking.

Comment: Glad could be of help